# For each loop continious but doesn't fill array

Tags: php, arrays, propel

***Problem***

Hey, my array `$isActiefErr` and `$naamErr` doesn't fill up after I throw an exception, but the foreach loop does continue to validate the values. I know the foreach loop keeps on looping, because the array which should have all the values is filled, but the error `array` stops after it encounters its first error.

***What I have tried:***

I've tried to print the `array` but it only pushes the first error into my array. It then stops validating. This also shows in my error log. I think the problem would be the try/catch, but I simply cannot confirm this, because of my lack of knowledge regarding try/catches.

***Question***

How can I get the array to push and display all the errors with a try/catch block surrounding it? Or am I simply missing something and isn't the problem related to the try/catch?

**This is my code:**

```
$validateOk = 0;
$setVar = new SetVariable();

$teller = 1;
$save = null;
$validateOk = 0;

$con->beginTransaction();
$weg = TypeQuery::create()->find();
$weg->delete();

try {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isEven($teller)) {
            $validateOk += $setVar->nameval($key)
                ->onerror($isActiefErr[]) //errors aren't being pushed into this array, besides the first one.
                ->validator(v::numericVal())
                ->go();
            if ($validateOk == 0) {
                $save->setCode(substr($key, 1));
                $save->setIsActief($value);
                $save->save();
            } else {
                //ROLLBACK/CATCH
                throw new Exception($error);
            }
        } else {
            $validateOk += $setVar->nameval($key)
                ->onerror($naamErr[])
                ->validator(v::alpha('/()éá&.,   '))
                ->go();
            if ($validateOk == 0) {
                $save = new Type();
                $save->setCode(substr($key, 1));
                $save->setNaam($value);
            } else {
                //ROLLBACK/CATCH
                throw new Exception($error);
            }
        }
        $teller += 1;
    }
    $con->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = "Het opslaan is fout gegaan!";
} {
    $con->rollback();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you say `Hey, my array $isActiefErr and $naamErr doesn't fill up after I throw an exception` but you've also said `I know the foreach loop keeps on looping, because the array with values are all filled`, surely that's a contradiction?

Comment: Correct, my bad. What I rather meant was: my array with values receives all the values, but the array which should receive the errors to later on output, stops after it encounters an error. It doesn't push the other 'not legal' values into the error array. I hope this made it a bit clearer :)

Comment: An exeption immediately terminates the `try` block. No loop will continue looping unless the try-catch construct is within the loop.